# if $G$ be Abelian group how $G/R$ can be also an Abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

assume that $G$ is a monoid and it has an equivalence $R(∼)$ such that $a_1∼a_2\ and\ b_1∼b_2$ and also for every $a_i,b_i\ ∈G$  we have $\ a_1b_1∼a_2b_2$.

proof $G/R$ based on the defined binary operation $\overline{a}\overline{b}=\overline{ab}$ is monoid and if $G$ be an Abelian group then $G/R$ is also an Abelian group.

my try:

if $G/R$ be monoid so for every $\overline{a},\overline{b},\overline{c}∈G/R$ the relation $\overline{a}(\overline{b}\overline{c})$ should be associative (to be semigroup) and for every $\bar{a}$ there should exist a specific element such $\overline{e}$ (to be monoid) and for every $\overline{a}$  there should exist a unique element $\overline{a^{-1}}$ ( to be group) .

my question is that what is exactly $\overline{a^{-1}}$ and $\overline{e}$ ( giving an example can be so useful) and also I know a group is Abelian if for every $a,b\ ∈\ G$ $ab=ba
$ , but here how $G/R$ can be Abelian?

Comment: Monoids need not have inverses.

Comment: yes I know, the last one is just because I want $G/R$ be a group.

Comment: It's only a group if $G$ is a group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be clear, we are saying that we have an equivalence relation on $G$ where $G$ can be either a monoid or an abelian group. The equivalence relation is not specified but has the property that if $a\sim b$ and $c\sim d$ then $ac\sim bd.$ If these conditions are met then $G/\sim$ maintains the structure, i.e. if $G$ is a monoid then the quotient is a monoid and if $G$ is an abelian group then the quotient is an abelian group where the product is defined as $[a][b]=[ab]$.

The first thing we must do is show that our product is well defined. Let $a'\sim a$ and $b'\sim b$. By the multiplication property of our equivalence relation we get that $a'b'\sim ab$ so $a'b'\in [ab]$. Therefore, multiplication in the quotient structure is well defined.

Let $a,b,c\in G$. Then $([a][b])[c]=[ab][c]=[(ab)c]=[a(bc)]=[a][bc]=[a]([b][c])$ so multiplication is associative. Since $e\in G$ for both monoids and abelian groups, $[e]\in G/\sim$ and for any $a\in G$, $[a][e]=[ae]=[a]=[ea]=[e][a]$. Therefore, $[e]$ is an identity in the quotient so the quotient is a monoid.

If $G$ is an abelian group then each $a\in G$ has an inverse $a^{-1}\in G$ and so has $[a^{-1}]$ in the guotient group. Moreover, $[a][a^{-1}]=[aa^{-1}]=[e]=[a^{-1}a]=[a^{-1}][a]$ so $[a^{-1}]$ is the inverse of [a] in the quotient.

Finally, if $ab=ba\in G$ then $[a][b]=[ab]=[ba]=[b][a]$ in the quotient group.

Therefore, $G/\sim$ is an abelian group.

Comment: Now I think we don't need to know that what is $\overline{a^{-1}}$ and $\overline{e}$ , we just need to know $∀a^{-1},e ∈ G:∃ \overline{a^{-1}},\overline{e} ∈ G/∼$ which $\overline{a^{-1}},\overline{e} ≠∅$ because $∀ a^{-1},e ∈ G: a ^{-1} ∈ \overline{a^{-1}}, e ∈ \overline{e}$.

Comment: That sounds right.

Comment: I want to show $ℤ$ with congruence modulo $m$ is an Abelian group if the ⊕ is defined as $∀a,b ∈ℤ:[a]+[b]=[a+b]$   
   fisrt of all $∀[a],[b],[c] ∈ ℤ/mℤ : [a]+([b]+[c])=[a]+([b+c])=[a+(b+c)]=[(a+b)+c]=[(a+b)]+[c]=([a]+[b])+[c]$, now  $∀[a] ∈ ℤ/mℤ:∃[e] which [a]+[e]=[a+e]=[e+a]=[e]+[a$]. then $∀[a] ∈ ℤ/mℤ:∃[-a] which [a]+[-a]=[a-a]=[e]=[-a+a]=[-a]+[a]$. and finally 4)$ ℤ/mℤ$ is Ableian if$ ∀[a]+[b]=[a+b]=[b+a]=[b]+[a]$ but how can we show that our binary operation is well-defined?

Comment: Show that it has the property that $n'\in [n]$ and $m'\in [m]$ implies that $[n'+m']\in [n+m]$.